# PHP Adspace Based On URL

Tags: php, url

On my website I have the following code:

```
<?php 
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (false!== strpos($url,'the-man')) {
    echo '<div class="ad_banner">';
    advert('advert_11');
} else {
    echo '<div class="ad_banner">';
    echo advert('advert_4');
}
```

?>

The code works fine. If the text `"the-man"` is found in the URL then `"advert_11"` is displayed and if not, `"advert_4"` is displayed.

I need the following:

If "the-man" is found in the URL then display `"advert_11"` AND IF `"the-dog"` is found in the URL then display `"advert_7"`. Else if neither are present in the URL then display `"advert_4"`

Comment: use if-else statement or switch case , that should work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you I understood what you wanted to do.

```
<?php     
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (false !== strpos($url,'the-man')) {

    echo '<div class="ad_banner">';
    advert('advert_11');

}else if (false !== strpos($url,'the-dog')) {

    echo '<div class="ad_banner">';
    advert('advert_7');
}
 else{
    echo '<div class="ad_banner">';
    echo advert('advert_4');
}

?>
```

Comment: You welcome man. You could have used switch statement too. But  I am glad that it worked for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're looking to do this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(strpos($url, 'the-man') !== false) {

    echo '<div class="ad_banner">';
    echo advert('advert_11');

    if(strpos($url, 'the-dog') !== false) {
        echo '<div class="ad_banner">';
        echo advert('advert_7');
    }
}
else if(strpos($url, 'the-dog') === false)) {
    echo '<div class="ad_banner">';
    echo advert('advert_4');
}
```